# MySQL InnoDB select data straight from index

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, innodb

If I make the following index on InnoDB table:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name on table_name (col1, col2)
```

and perform this select query:

```
SELECT col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1=some_value
```

will MySQL retrieve col2 straight from index?

(What I'm trying to achieve is to drastically speed up the selection process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should. That's called [index-only scan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/index-only-scan).

But to be sure, you should examine the query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL will use index automatically, though SQLite will do. Try:

```
SELECT col2 FROM table_name use index (col1,col2) WHERE col1=some_value
```